# How to validate form by validator add method with show loading image when validation is under process to form submit event?

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate form using jquery with 2 server side validation.Server side validation is taking some time to validate inputs,So i want to show loader image while form validation is under process.Below i mentioned cases which i want to do.

1. On submit form display loading and if form have invalid inputs then hide loader and show error messages.
2. If form have valid inputs submit form using ajax and loader will continue till ajax response.
   Below i mentioned sample code

```
$(function(){

    var add_manager_form = $("form[name='add_manager']");

    $(add_manager_form).submit(function(e) {
        $('.ajax-loader').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        add_manager_form.validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            onfocusout: false,
            rules: {
              first_name: "required",
              last_name: "required",
              employee_id: {
                required: true,
                // uniqueEmployeeId: true
              },
              contact_number: "required",
              email: {
                required: true,
                // uniqueEmailId: true
              },
            },
            messages: {
              first_name: "First Name is required",
              last_name: "Last Name is required",
              contact_number: "Contact Number is required",
              employee_id: {
                required: "Employee ID is required"
              },
              email: {
                required: "Email is required"
              }
            }
      });
      console.log(add_manager_form.valid());     
      if(add_manager_form.valid() !== false){
        $.ajax({
            url: add_manager_form.action, 
            type:"POST",
            data: $(add_manager_form).serialize(),
            cache: false,             
            processData: false, 
            success: function(data) {
               $('.ajax-loader').hide();
               var resp = JSON.parse(data);
               if(resp.status == "success"){
                 $('.alert-success-msg').text(resp.msg);
                 location.reload(true);
               }else{
                 $('.alert-error-msg').text(resp.msg);
               }
            }
        });
      }else{
        $('.ajax-loader').hide();
      } 

    });  





    /****  validator methods ****/
    $.validator.addMethod("uniqueEmailId", 
        function(value, element) {
            var result = false;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async: false,
                url: "/project/email/check_unique", // script to validate in server side
                data: {email: value},
                success: function(data) {
                    result = (data == "Y") ? true : false;
                }
            });
            // return true if username is exist in database
            return result; 
        }, 
        "Email already exist, please try with another email address"
    );
    $.validator.addMethod("uniqueEmployeeId", 
        function(value, element) {
            var result = false;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async: false,
                url: "/project/employee_id/check_unique", // script to validate in server side
                data: {employee_id: value},
                success: function(data) {
                    result = (data == "Y") ? true : false;
                }
            });
            // return true if username is exist in database
            return result; 
        }, 
        "Employee ID already exist, please try with another employee id"
    );

});
```

If i comment uniqueEmployeeId and uniqueEmailId method then loader working fine but when i uncomment this two validation loader stopped working. Please give me answer if anything is gone wrong OR please suggest me if you have better way to validate form with server side validation and loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `remote` option.
please check the documentation of jquery form validation for email address.
https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/